# How to access \p{P} and \p{S} in python re

Tags: python, regex

For the python built-in regex import re I can't seem to get the regex "\p{P}" and "\p{S}" to work.

These work on regex101.com but when I use them to match with python using something like r"[\p{P}\p{S}]" I get a regex error for a bad escape.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this for python.

Is there a python equivalent to match punctuation and symbols?

Comment: I don't think python `re` have support for shorthand classes of punctuation and symbols. These doesn't work on regex101 if you choose the python flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Python's standard library `re` doesn't support `\p` which is the likely cause of the error. (For future reference, you should share some code that causes the error, as well as the full error itself, for better answers)

You can install and import the third party library `regex`:

```
pip install regex
```

And then:

```
import regex

print(regex.findall('\p{P}', 'a, b.'))
```

Result:

```
[',', '.']
```